# Docker container Windows, connect via RDP or VNC Client

Tags: docker, window, rdp, vnc-server

Can't see visually a windows 10 container.

I have tried to connect via RDP (exposing 3389 port via `-p 3389:3389`)

I know that inside the container there is a virtual monitor (emulated at 1240x768). I have created a node server that return me a sceeenshot from the desktop with this plugin:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/screenshot-desktop

Using it locally work like a charm, I see a screenshot of my current monitor. But when i try to run it inside the container i see a black screen, so maybe it's impossible to connect visually...

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1903
# FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1903

EXPOSE 3389
```

```
docker run -it --rm -p 3389:3389 sample:dev
```

I tried 2 base image but result it's the same

I would see what is happening inside the container, like a VM.

Comment: see this https://withinrafael.com/2018/03/09/using-remote-desktop-services-in-containers/

Comment: I have tried this guide... With the latest version that should works (the version indicated on the notes at start of this guide) but nothing changed, i can't connect to the container

Comment: been trying to crack this egg as well for the past couple of days. You will notice that the termservices service is not even running and is disabled. I've managed to get it to start but a listening port on 3389 never appears in the container. I've checked a few registry entries, and added the one from the link but alas no yolk. Also been attempting a solution via a VNC connection with tightVNC, but no joy here either...yet.

Answer (score 9):

There is no RDP support for windows containers at this time.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f4314bc8-52d0-477c-9ecc-86a578b53814/no-support-expected-for-rdp-in-containers-for-windows-server-2016?forum=windowscontainers

I've also been trying to get a container running VNC and have opened a ticket with the TightVNC team you can see here:

https://sourceforge.net/p/vnc-tight/bugs/1483/

Comment: Keen to get this working too. [Here](https://serverfault.com/questions/984285/connect-to-tightvnc-in-a-windows-container) is my attempts, commented on your ticket too. Also tried with realVNC but their installer is problematic and I cant event get it to run properly in a VM.

Comment: My next idea is to try cygwin/x with xfce but it's going to be a while before I can attempt.